# Trouble creating an R package with _roxygen2_

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am having trouble creating an R package with *roxygen2* . Here is my code:

```
require(devtools)
require(roxygen2)
setwd("C://Users//pfeiffer.s@pg.com//Documents//sp th//R stuff")
create("myfunctions")
```

At this point, I used Windows File Explorer to add .R files to the folder "R" within the folder "myfunctions".

```
setwd("C:/Users/pfeiffer.s@pg.com/Documents/sp th/R stuff//myfunctions")
document()
setwd("C:/Users/pfeiffer.s@pg.com/Documents/sp th/R stuff")
install("myfunctions")
```

Everything appeared to work properly, but:

```
?vectorize #one of the .R files I added
```

> No documentation for ‘vectorize’ in specified packages and libraries:
>   you could try ‘??vectorize’

Comment: This example is not reproducible and doesn't give much to help diagnose.  This is grounds for closing a question but will refrain as you're a new poster.  Please read the question guidelines and make changes to make this question suitable. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you didn't load the package after you installed it.

Instead of

```
install("myfunctions")
```

Try running

```
install("myfunctions")
library("myfunctions")
```